# joomla component searching

Tags: php, joomla, components

Please assist my model is able to get the data from the database but am not able to filter if i want a specific result set it keeps giving me the same data

This is my code. Thanks For the help in advance

```
public function __construct($config = array()) {
                $config['filter_fields']=array(
                'b.start', 
                'd.`title` ', 
                'e.`title`');
                parent::__construct($config);
        }

     function getListQuery()
     {
     $db = JFactory::getDBO();
         $query = $db->getQuery(true);
     $query->select('a.firstname, a.lastname, b.start, c.flightnumber, d.`title` TO_NAME, e.`title` FROM_NAME, c.id');  
     $query->from(' #__bookpro_passenger as a');
     $query->JOIN('INNER', '#__bookpro_orderinfo as b ON a.order_id = b.order_id');
     $query-> JOIN('INNER','#__bookpro_flight as c ON b.obj_id = c.id');
     $query-> JOIN('INNER','#__bookpro_dest as d ON c.desfrom = d.id');
     $query->  JOIN('INNER',' #__bookpro_dest as e ON c.desto = e.id');



       $destfrom = $this->getState('filter.from');
                if (!empty($destfrom)) {
                $destfrom = $db->Quote('%'.$db->escape($destfrom, true).'%');
                $query->where('(e.`title` LIKE '.$destfrom.')');
    }


       $destfrom = $this->getState('filter.to');
                if (!empty($destfrom)) {
                $destto = $db->Quote('%'.$db->escape($destto, true).'%');
                $query->where('( d.`title` LIKE '.$destto.')');
    }
    return $query;
    }

     function populateState()
        {

                $app = JFactory::getApplication();


                $destfrom = $app->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context.'.filter.from', 'filter_from');

                $this->setState('filter.from', $destfrom);
                $destto = $app->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context.'.filter.to', 'filter_to');

                $this->setState('filter.to', $destto);


                parent::populateState();
    }
}
```

Comment: Without table and form detail it's hard to tell what is the issue. Additionally second `if` condition also looks incorrect.It should be `$destto = $this->getState('filter.to');if (!empty($destto)) {`

Answer (score 0):

You should also override populateState() in your model for the `filter.to`, and `filter.from`:

```
protected function populateState($ordering = null, $direction = null) {
  $app = JFactory::getApplication('administrator');
  $filter.to = $app->input->get('filter.to');
  $this->setState('filter.to', $rfilter.to);
  // ...
  // your default sorting
  parent::populateState('a.firstname', 'asc');
}
```

Either way, check if the `$this->getState('filter.from')` is the set correctly.